# Cascade Delete from DB, by some params("WHERE value=..."), using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, cascade, cascading-deletes

In Bean class there is this annotation:

```
   class User {  
        @OneToMany(targetEntity = Feedback.class,mappedBy = "user",cascade =   
        CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
    private List<Feedback> feedbacks;  
        ...  
    }
```

I want to delete user, which has some feedbacks.
If I type this:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, id));
```

user will be deleted successfully, (id is primary key). But I want to delete all users, witch, have role="admin", and if i type this query:

```
String query = "DELETE from User WHERE role='" + role + "'";
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query).executeUpdate();
```

It will be delete only users without references to feedbacks. What wrong with my query? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with your query.  HQL delete queries do not "touch" associations.  That is per JPA spec.

Check out [this issue](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-695) in Hibernate Jira about adding support for adding a new keyword CASCADE to delete queries for specifying associations which should also be deleted.